# Laravel Eloquent doesn't delete model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table known as identifier table, which has the primary key as a foreign key to another table:

```
[TABLE 1] id (PK) ..attributes
[TABLE 2] table1_id (PK, FK) ...attributes
```

I already defined on "TABLE 2" model the attribute `$primaryKey = table1_id`.

When I try to delete **table 2** record, the return value is true, but nothing happens.

I've tried it three ways:

`$table1->table2()->delete()`

`Table2::where('table1_id', $table1_id)->delete()`

`Table2::find($table1_id)->delete()`

and

`DB::table('table2')->where('table1_id', $table1_id)->delete()`

And both three return true, but nothing really happens.

Any light? Should I open issue on Laravel's repo?

Comment: Are you using soft deletes?

Comment: @Dale on `Table 1`, yes. But the table I am trying to delete records is `Table 2`, which wont use SD.

Answer (score 1):

```
Table1::find(id)->delete()
```

and

```
Table2::find(id)->delete()
```

since they are the same keys.

try this without the () on table2:

```
$table1->table2->delete()
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same result. Will update question.

Comment: Try passing in the table2 id then, that indicates it's using prepared statements and expects bindings to be passed in.